# Fama/French 3 Factors: How to convert published daily/weekly/monthly values to semi-annual/annual?

Tags: regression, factor-models, fama-french

In the famous [Ken French web side](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html) there is database of historical values of FF 3 factors model. The partition is between daily/weekly/monthly tables.

1. Is it possible (and how) to transform one of these tables to semi-annual/annual table?
2. If not, is there a way to calculate semi-annual/annual tables based on other data from this web site? Note - The issue is to calculate values based on free public available data, assuming paid access to CRSP etc. N/A.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following paper has a good discussion on the topic:

[On the Consistency between the Fama-French Daily and Monthly Factors](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228267016_On_the_Consistency_between_the_Fama-French_Daily_and_Monthly_Factors)

Basically you should cumulate monthly ones to get to annual numbers.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. What you mean by "cumulate"?

Comment: (1+HML1)*(1+HML2)*...*(1+HML12)-1 for example

Answer (score 1):

Most French website data contains annual factors too. You just have to scroll to the bottom of the text file after the monthly data.

Also, this is a [related question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18808/french-data-from-daily-to-monthly-returns).